# How does it affect the equilibrium expression if the concentration of any component remains the same?

Tags: physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, equilibrium, kinetics

I am a high school student and I am very confused in Equilibrium expression, My confusion is that "Why we don't write concentration of solids and pure liquids in equilibrium expression?" Many people says that its because their concentration don't changes but how does it related to this? If concentration is same for them then what's the issue in it? I am not able to picturize how does it affect the equilibrium expression if their concentration remain the same?

please Help me regarding this using simple language that I can understand because I am at high school level. If anyone could help me to picturize this thing in my mind then it would be very helpful.

Comment: Well, it **doesn't**, so it can be ignored, as simple as that.

Comment: Well, you can either define an equilibrium constant with the formal constant concentration of a pure condensed phase in mol/dm3, or you can implicitly involve them in the equilibrium constant value, pretending their concentration is 1 mol/dm3. Why way is more convenient ? The same for the pressure variant of the equilibrium constant.

Comment: why we have to pretend that their concentration is  1mol/dm^3,.it can be of any value..

Comment: We do not have to. Neither we have to go along stairs forwards. We can go backwards as well. Multiplication or division by 1 is very convenient. You can omit it totally.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to study the equilibrium of the reaction of a metal like zinc $\ce{Zn}$ with water to produce $\ce{ZnO(s)}$ and $\ce{H2}$ :$$\ce{Zn(s) + H2O(g) <=> ZnO(s) + H2(g)}$$ At high temperature, the equilibrium constant may be written $$K_\mathrm{1}=\frac{[\ce{ZnO}]·p\ce{(H2)}}{[\ce{Zn}]·p\ce{(H2O)}}$$ In this expression three parameters are not changing : the constant $K_\mathrm{1}$, and the two concentrations of the solid stuffs $\ce{Zn}$ and $\ce{ZnO}$ in their own phases. The mass of these stuffs may change but not their concentrations, as they are in the solid phase. So it is no use keeping such a formula where three parameters are constant. It is better to group all constant parameters on the same side of the = sign, and define a new constant like $K_\mathrm{2}$ : $$K_\mathrm{2} = K_\mathrm{1}\frac{[\ce{Zn}]}{[\ce{ZnO}]}= \frac{p\ce{(H2)}}{p\ce{(H2O)}}$$ With this formula and a numerical value for $K_\mathrm{2}$ you may calculate immediately how $p\ce{(H2)}$ changes when $p\ce{(H2O)}$ is varied. No need to know the concentration of the solids. This may be useful if you want to optimize the yield in producing $\ce{H2}$ gas through this reaction.

Comment: so this new constant include all the constants in it, this also creates a problem  in my mind that the equilibrium constant tells us whether the concentration of product is high or low than the reactant at equilibrium, but if we are including the concentration of solid in this new constant then we would have get some higher value for Keq. which we MIGHT not get if the a reaction has some solid reactants in it, so it  creates a new problem ,

Comment: I don't see your point. The ratio of the concentrations of Zn in metallic zinc and ZnO in the solid ZnO is a constant, which should not be important, and probably between $0.1$ and $10$. I don't speak of the amounts, in mass or in moles. I just speak about the concentrations.

Comment: I am not only talking about this reaction, I am talking about those reactions in which those solids are involved which have a higher concentration.

Comment: Whatever the nature of the solids appearing in a chemical reaction, their concentrations stay constant

Comment: I know their concentration stay constant, but what I am saying is that, if we consider their concentration  to be the part of Keq. itself and do not count them in the expression then how can we predict that at equilibrium the concentration of product is high or reactant is high? we should consider them in the expression.

Comment: Only $K_2$ values are reported in Table of constants.

Comment: but in some reactions like esterification reaction in which water is formed as a product ,then we do consider its concentration also in in the expression, why is it so?

Comment: Whatever the reaction, when the solvent is also included in the reactants of a chemical reaction, the concentration of the solvant is considered as constant, and its expression is included in the equilibrium constant. It is not the cas in an esterification which produces water without being made in water. In this case, the amount of water is changing during the reaction. Here the concentration of water is not constant. So it remains among the variables that are combined to be equal to the equilibrium constant.